# Howto add and link to existing WebSite project from ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an existing Website project; its just one .html and a bunch of .js files (all client-side stuff). This project only has a .sln file, no *.*proj files. It's directory structure is basically:

```
WEB_PROJECT_ROOT/apps/foo/index.html
WEB_PROJECT_ROOT/lib/*.js
```

Now I'm working on a new ASP.NET Forms Application, and I need to link to index.html page above, but I'd like to keep it as a separate project (and not just copy it into the new ASP.NET project). It's structure is basically:

```
APP_PROJECT_ROOT/Pages/*.aspx
```

I've done Add -> Existing Project and chosen the .sln from above, and it shows up in the ASP.NET solution, but I can't figure out how to link to index.html because it's outside of the ASP.NET project's ~/ directory. Is there are way to symlink to it somehow? Or something else?

Comment: Have you tried "Add ... Existing Web Site"?

Comment: That appears to do the same thing as Add -> Existing Project. It gets it to show up in my new solution, but I can't link to it.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you are attempting to accomplish. Why can't you just copy it? If that existing website project is published somewhere, you just reference those files via their URLs. i.e. `<script src="http://localhost/WEB_PROJECT_ROOT/lib/Foo.js" />`

Comment: Nothing is published, yet. I'd like to avoid copying it because its more than a handful of files, and it is still used separately; I don't want to fork it. I guess I'm look for a way to create some sort of virtual directory in web.config that says "~/apps/" == "some/physical/path".

Comment: When you publish your project, you will need to link to them anyway, so you may as well code for that inevitability. For development, on your machine, set up a virtual directory in IIS and link to the other project's files. Then use the <script src> tag to reference them.